# How to correctly prevent Firebase to collect absolutely any data temporarily?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a switch button so that the user can accept consent of data collection of Firebase (I use some services like Analytics, Crashlytics...) if the switch is on .Also he can turn it off whenever he wants to decline this consent.

I have seen in the official documentation that I can disable Analytics or Crashlytics, but I think that isn't enough as some data is collected by Firebase even if the services are disabled.

Okay, so as you can think, what I want to implement is a method to enable and disable everything related to Firebase whenever the user wants so that any data is collected if the switch is off and the services work if the switch is on.

Comment: Please do not repeat your questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry, I'm a little desperate to find a solution